# Python optimisation of knapsack-type combination with extra constraint

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, permutation, knapsack-problem

I have several vectors of scores, for example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [6,8,2,1]
C = [2,7,9,4]
D = [4,3,2,1]
```

Where each score position corresponds to a cost on a separate cost vector:

```
   cost = [0.25,0.5,0.75,1]
```

For example picking '8' from vector B carries a cost of 0.5.

How do I choose only one item from each of A to D which maximises the sum value (as per knapsack problem). This is subject to two constraints:

1) a budget constraint. i.e. if '*' denotes the position of the optimum combination in a vector, then:

```
cost[A*]+cost[B*]+cost[C*]+cost[D*] == budget
```

2) a range constraint on each vector, such that there is a minimum and maximum spend from each vector that can be set. i.e:

```
0.2 < cost[C*] < 0.6
```

I attempted a brute force version of http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1#C.2B.2B.
But I wasn't sure how to expand it to multiple lists and I am certain there is a more elegant solution. Does not necessarily have to be knapsack approach.

Comment: Post your code, please. You don't want to just drop a problem from a coding site and leave.

Comment: Agree. Though I do not have code as what I tried was a dead end and I would rather avoid brute force. So the question is to see what else is available as I'm at a loss.